# PHP Update Cart Array

Tags: php, arrays, cart

Basically I've been writing an UpdateCart function to a Shop class. The idea is the Cart is a Session Array, That an item is added as a new number in an Array like `array(1 => array(), 2 = array()` and so on.

```
public function updateCart($ID, $Proc) {
    switch($Proc) {
        case $Proc = "Add" :
            try {
                $item = $this->_db->get("Shop","WHERE $ID = id");
                $this->cartArray[ count($this->cartArray) + 1 ] = array (
                    "ID" => $item['id'],
                    "Name" => $item['name'],
                    "Desc" => $item['desc'],
                    "Price" => $item['price']
                );
                session::put('ShoppingCart', $this->cartArray);
                print_r($_SESSION['ShoppingCart']);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die("No Item with That ID Found");
            }
            break;
        case $Proc = "Remove" :
            echo "Item ".$item['ID']." Removed";

            break;
        default:
            echo "Nothing to do";
            break;
    }
}
```

The only problem is it doesn’t add to a Array, it just Completely replaces, and I'm racking my brains to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your array each time you call put, try push instead.

```
public function updateCart($ID, $Proc)
{
    switch ($Proc) {
        case $Proc = "Add" :
            try {
                $item = $this->_db->get("Shop", "WHERE $ID = id");
                $this->cartArray[] = array(
                    "ID" => $item['id'],
                    "Name" => $item['name'],
                    "Desc" => $item['desc'],
                    "Price" => $item['price']
                );
                session::push('ShoppingCart', $this->cartArray);
                print_r($_SESSION['ShoppingCart']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die("No Item with That ID Found");
            }
            break;
        case $Proc = "Remove" :
            echo "Item " . $item['ID'] . " Removed";
            break;
        default:
            echo "Nothing to do";
    }
}
```

If this also doesn't work, try to merge it when you use put

```
public function updateCart($ID, $Proc)
{
    switch ($Proc) {
        case $Proc = "Add" :
            try {
                $item = $this->_db->get("Shop", "WHERE $ID = id");
                $this->cartArray[] = array(
                    "ID" => $item['id'],
                    "Name" => $item['name'],
                    "Desc" => $item['desc'],
                    "Price" => $item['price']
                );
                session::put('ShoppingCart', array_merge(session::get('ShoppingCart'), $this->cartArray));
                print_r($_SESSION['ShoppingCart']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die("No Item with That ID Found");
            }
            break;
        case $Proc = "Remove" :
            echo "Item " . $item['ID'] . " Removed";
            break;
        default:
            echo "Nothing to do";
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the second method, and it works Perfectly Thanks!